# How to get correct logic truth table results with two inputs in pygame without having to press both inputs at exactly the right time

Tags: python, pygame, boolean, logic

I'm planning on making a keyboard that uses only 5 keys by using different combinations of switch presses but there's one thing I can't figure out how to resolve so I want to try and recreate a basic example of the board in python using keyboard presses to simulate the buttons which would have been in real life.

Say I had a red button and a blue button. When I press only the red button I should hypothetically get an output of "A". When I press only the blue button I should get an output of "B" and when I press both at the same time, I should get an output of "C".

The problem is I would have to press the red and blue button at exactly the same time for the computer to understand that I want the output "C" and if I press one before the other, I get two characters outputted rather than one.

I haven't really written any code for it but I would like someone to help me solve this problem so that I can implement it into my PyGame program and then onto an Arduino later on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something quick like a dictionary-based lookup table would work.  On the Arduino I would use a 2-byte lookup table in a speed+space efficient data structure though.

```
### Chord key mapping table
key_table = {  "a"  : "a",
               "s"  : "e",
               "d"  : "i",
               "f"  : "o",
               "g"  : "u",
               "as" : "s",
               "ad" : "t",
               "af" : "n"   }
```

In the main loop build up the map-key by looking at the `pygame.key.get_pressed()` tuple:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
# print( str( keys ) )

chord_pressed = ''
if ( keys[pygame.K_a] ):   # note: the order the chord is made 
    chord_pressed += 'a'   #       is significant
if ( keys[pygame.K_s] ):
    chord_pressed += 's'
if ( keys[pygame.K_d] ):
    chord_pressed += 'd'
if ( keys[pygame.K_f] ):
    chord_pressed += 'f'
if ( keys[pygame.K_g] ):
    chord_pressed += 'g'

if ( chord_pressed in key_table.keys() ):
    print( "[%s] → [%s]" % ( chord_pressed, key_table[ chord_pressed ] ) )
```

Seems to work OK:

> [a] → [a]
>   [a] → [a]
>   [as] → [s]
>   [as] → [s]
>   [as] → [s]